# How can I download files with Fastify? Nest js

Tags: node.js, nestjs, fastify

Multer cannot process data which is not in the supported multipart format (multipart/form-data).

Also, note that this package is not compatible with the FastifyAdapter.

I tried use  @fastify/multipart, but I did not see error if files for example 3 and I can not set limit size.

What is the best way to upload files?

I tried:

```
 async uploadFile(req: FastifyRequest, res: FastifyReply<any>): Promise<any> {
    // upload file
    try {
      //Check request is multipart
      if (!req.isMultipart()) {
        res.send(
          new BadRequestException(
            new AppResponseDto(400, undefined, 'Request is not multipart'),
          ),
        );
        return;
      }
      //
      const options = {
        limits: {
          fieldSize: 1, // Max field value size in bytes
        },
      };
      const mp = await req.multipart(handler, onEnd, options);
      // for key value pairs in request
      mp.on('file', function (key: any, value: any) {
        // console.log('form-data', key, value,'<');
      });
      //Save files in directory
      async function handler(
        field: string,
        file: any,
        filename: string,
        encoding: string,
        mimetype: string,
      ): Promise<void> {
        const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);
        const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(`uploads/${filename}`); //File path
        try {
          await pipeline(file, writeStream);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error('Pipeline failed', err);
        }
      }
      // Uploading finished
      async function onEnd(err: any) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(new HttpException('Internal server error', 500));
          return;
        }
        res
          .code(200)
          .send(
            new AppResponseDto(200, undefined, 'Data uploaded successfully'),
          );
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Full code:
https://github.com/Ihorhavryliak/test_fastify_multipart

Comment: Wow, Please explain: "but I did not see error if files for example 3 and I can not set limit size." (you can use [edit] to do that)

Comment: You can test it here GitHub Repo: 

https://github.com/Ihorhavryliak/test_fastify_multipart
1. try downloading a file with a big size

Comment: I do not want to test, I want you to tell me.... 

Comment: When I download a file of more than 2MB - for example, I expected to see an error, also I can set a max download of 3 files, but I do not see an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code, What I did is, I get the multipart file from the request, did some validation, store the file in the server's file system, and finally store the file path in the database.

main.ts

```
import fastifyMultipart from '@fastify/multipart';

  app.register(fastifyMultipart, {
    attachFieldsToBody: true,
    limits: { fileSize: 1000000000 } // 1GB
  });
```

**post.controller.ts**

```
export class PostController {
  constructor(private readonly postService: PostService) {}

  @Post('posts')
  async createPost(
    @Req() req: FastifyRequest,
    @Res() reply: FastifyReply,
  ) {
    const file = req.file();
    try {
      await this.postService.create(file);
      reply
        .code(HttpStatus.CREATED)
        .send({ message: 'Post created successfully' });
    } catch (error) {
      reply.send(error);
    }
  }
```

**post.service.ts**

```
  async create(
    file: Promise<MultipartFile>,
  ) {
    try {
      const { mimetype: fileType, filename } = await file;

      if (!FILE_TYPES.includes(fileType))
        throw new UnprocessableEntityException(
          `file type should be anyone of the ${FILE_TYPES.join(', ')}`
        );

      const fileExtension = this.getFileExtension(filename);
      const fileName = `${moment().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')}.${fileExtension}`;
      const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../../../../src', 'assets');

      const base64 = (await (await file).toBuffer()).toString('base64');
      const buf = Buffer.from(base64, 'base64');
      fs.writeFile(`${filePath}/${fileName}`, buf, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          throw error;
        }
      });

      const image_url = `nest-lib/assets/${fileName}`; /* FIXME: NEED TO UPDATE RIGHT FILE PATH IN DATABASE */
      const currentDate = new Date();
      const postCreateAttrs = {
        image_url,
        created_at: currentDate,
        updated_at: currentDate
      };
      return await this.prisma.post.create({
        data: postCreateAttrs
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

This approach can be helpful to you

Answer (score -2):

Examples:

```js
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  HttpStatus,
  ParseFilePipeBuilder,
  Post,
  UploadedFile,
  UploadedFiles,
  UseInterceptors,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  AnyFilesInterceptor,
  File,
  FileInterceptor,
} from '@nest-lab/fastify-multer';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';
import { extname } from 'path';
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  //many files
  @Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(
    AnyFilesInterceptor({
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './uploads',
        filename: (req, file, callback) => {
          const uniqueSuffix =
            Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
          const ext = extname(file.originalname);
          const filename = `${uniqueSuffix}${ext}`;
          callback(null, filename);
        },
      }),
      limits: {
        files: 1,
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5, // 5MB
      },
    }),
  )
  async uploadFile(@UploadedFiles() files: any) {
    console.log(files);
  }
  //a file
  @Post('/file')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './uploads',
        filename: (req, file, callback) => {
          const uniqueSuffix =
            Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
          const ext = extname(file.originalname);
          const filename = `${'uniqueSuffix'}${ext}`;
          callback(null, filename);
        },
      }),
    }),
  )
  handleUpload(
    @UploadedFile(
      new ParseFilePipeBuilder()
        .addFileTypeValidator({
          fileType: 'jpeg',
        })
        .addMaxSizeValidator({
          maxSize: 1000,
        })
        .build({
          errorHttpStatusCode: HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
        }),
    )
    file: File,
  ) {
    console.log('file', file);
    return 'File upload API';
  }
}
```

Comment: It'd be much better if you explain what you've learned and what has fixed your problem instead of just sharing a piece of code